# Acessando uma array que esteja dentro de outra

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte array

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["data"]=>
    string(19) "2015-11-20 00:33:53"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["data"]=>
    string(19) "2015-11-20 08:24:50"
  }
}
```

Como faço para acessar as duas `['data']`'s ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da seguinte forma:

```
echo $seuArray[0]['data'];
echo $seuArray[1]['data'];
```

Ou também por um laço for:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($seuArray); $i++) {
    echo $seuArray[$i]['data'];
}
```

Ou com laço foreach:

```
foreach($seuArray as $item) {
    echo $item['data'];
}
```